# Initialization order and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following sample code snipped.
It seems to me that the code leads to UB. Does it?
From one point of view, `std::move()` just makes type cast on `x` and nothing more. From other, `z` can be move-constructed before `x.val` dereferencing. Can it?

```
struct s {
    std::shared_ptr<int> val;
};
void fun2(int a, s z) {
}
void fun(s x) {
    fun2(*(x.val), std::move(x));
}
```

Comment: Just grab the value into a named variable before calling the function. Besides appearing less dependent on dark corners of C++, it will actually read more clearly . Oh, and no, there is no dark corner to hide in. What you wrote is dangerous code.

Answer (score 3):

> From one point of view, std::move() just makes type cast on x and nothing more

That is not correct. Since `fun2` expects an object, an object is constructed by using the compiler generated move constructor.

> From other, z can be move-constructed before x.val dereferencing. Can it?

Yes, it can. Since order of evaluation of the arguments in a function call is not specified by the standard, it is possible for `x` to be *moved* before `*(x.val)` is evaluated.

Your program is subject to undefined behavior.